# phalcon framework -> edit model::find(); results in an foreach loop

Tags: object, phalcon, volt

As http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#understanding-records-to-objects says, you can edit the objects once its loaded in the memory.

```
    $settingCategories = SettingCategory::find();
    foreach($settingCategories as $settingCategory){
        if($settingCategory->type == "2"){
            $settingCategory->type = "asd";
            $settingCategory->intersection = "asd";
        }else{
            $settingCategory->type = "blaa";
            $settingCategory->intersection = "blaa";
        }
        $settingCategory->type = "test";
    }
    $this->view->setVar("settingCategories",$settingCategories);
```

type is still its default value when I loop through it with volt:

```
{% for settingCategory in settingCategories %}
<div class="tab-content">
    <h4>{{ settingCategory.name }}</h4> 
    <h4>{{ settingCategory.type }}</h4> --> still (int) integer!?
    <h4>{{ settingCategory.intersection }}</h4> --> undefined!?
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are modifying a variable inside a foreach, you are modifying a "temporary variable". What it means is that since it is only a *copy* of the real variable, when you change it, the real value inside the array isn't changed. Now, on to what you could do to solve this:

### Setters/Getters

I personally prefer this one. If what you want to do is data transformation (I.E. you change the value of a field from one thing to another, and you want to use the new value in your code everywhere), I would use setters and getters. Here is an example:

```
// This is inside your model
protected $type;

public function getType()
{
    if ($this->type === 2) {
        return "asd";
    } else {
        return $this->type;
    }
}

public function setType($type)
{
    if ($type === 2) {
        $this->type = "asd";
    } else {
        $this->type = 1; // or $type, or anything really :)
    }
}
```

Of course, in your code, you'll have to change `$category->type` to `$category->getType()` and `$category->setType($type)`, based on whether you are reading the value or assigning something to it.

### The Quick and Dirty Way

Well, if your use case is different, you can use your current code block with a simple modification. Change your foreach to `foreach($settingCategories as &$settingCategory)`. The ampersand makes the variable be passed into the block as a reference (I.E. it is not a copy like your current case). That means changing it will change the real value.